# Loop through 2 lists in Excel with VBA to copy tab data from one to another

Tags: excel, vba, loops, copy

I have 2 sets of ranges; Source file paths and Destination file paths.

I want to loop through each list to open the source file and copy a tab/sheet to the destination file path.

Below is the code I have used to loop through the Source list and copy data from a tab in that workbook and paste it to a named sheet. The copy tab is named in the offset ,1 code below and the paste name will never change.

This step prepares the workbook so i can now copy this tab to a completely separate workbook that I have listed.

Is this possible to do efficiently with a for loop??

```
Sub RollQuarter()

Dim Wbk As Workbook
Dim Wks As Worksheet
Dim Filepath As String, Filename As String, sStg As String
Dim oDic As Scripting.Dictionary
Dim rng As Range, c As Range
Dim varKey As Variant

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
End With

Set oDic = New Scripting.Dictionary
oDic.CompareMode = TextCompare

sStg = ""

Set rng = Union(Range("dummy")) 'Source files
 
For Each c In rng.Cells
    If Not oDic.Exists(c.Value) Then
        oDic.Add c.Value, c.Offset(, 1).Value
    Else
        MsgBox "Duplicate Item found", vbInformation, "Error Message"
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next c

For Each varKey In oDic.Keys
    If Len(Dir(varKey)) = 0 Then
        If sStg = "" Then
            sStg = oDic.Item(varKey)
        Else
            sStg = sStg & ", " & vbCrLf & oDic.Item(varKey)
        End If
    Else
        On Error Resume Next
        Set Wbk = Workbooks.Open(varKey, False)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Wbk Is Nothing Then
        Else
            With Wbk
                .Sheets(oDic.Item(varKey)).Cells.Copy
                .Sheets("dummy sheet").Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
                .Save
            End With

            Wbk.Close False
            Set Wbk = Nothing
        End If
    End If

Next varKey

.....

If Len(sStg) > 0 Then MsgBox "The below files do not exist" & vbCrLf _
                        & sStg, vbCritical

End Sub
```

Comment: Not entirely clear what you are asking. From the look of your code, it looks like you're already pretty well sorted for finishing the solution. Efficiency is a vague term. Do you want space (memory) efficiency, speed efficiency, or perhaps some other kind of efficiency? I would guess using a 'for' loop will likely be fine for you, but it does depend on what kinds of efficiencies you want.

Comment: Hi Mark - The above code only allows me to open a workbook, and copy data within that workbook, then close and open the next workbook in the range. I now want a function that will allow me to open 2 seperate workbooks, copy from one to another and then close both workbooks and open the next 2 in their repespective ranges and repeat the steps.